# the inverse of a sum of two symmetric for schur completion?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-decomposition, schur-complement

I have a up-triangulate Jacobi matrix J which can be blocked like :

$J = \begin{bmatrix}A & B\\ 0 & C\end{bmatrix}  $

both A and C are up-triangulate, we can get Hessian matrix H by:

$H = J'J =\begin{bmatrix}A' & 0\\B'&C'\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}A & B\\ 0 & C\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A'A & A'B\\B'A & B'B+C'C\end{bmatrix} $

by schur completion, I want to margin $B'B+C'C$, the equation is:

$ A'A - A'B(B'B+C'C)^{-1}B'A $

I know $C^{-1}$ is easy computed because it's a up-triangulate matrix, but unfortunately the add ruin this equation.

I have found that 
$ X(X^{-1}+Y^{-1})Y = (X^{-1}+Y^{-1})^{-1} $ only when both X and Y are invertible, which B'B dose not meet

so any one have some brilliant idea to compute this equation easily?

Comment: I understand most of your question, but I don't understand this: *"by schur completion, I want to margin $B'B+C'C$"*.  What are you trying to say here?  What do you mean by "margin"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you for your attention , basically margin means remove some target variable in optimization problem , you can refer it from g2o paper https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~kzhang/papers/g2o.pdf , equ(25)

Comment: If $B$ (or $B^TB$) has low rank you can update the cholesky decomposition $C^TC$

Comment: @LinAlg yes B'B is not full rank , could you give me some more information about "update the cholesky decomposition" ?

Comment: @LinAlg thank you for your hint, I think cholesky decomposition update should be work

Comment: So, when you say that you want to *"marginalize $B'B + C'C$"*, does that just mean that you want to compute the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) $M/(B'B + C'C)$?  That is, are you just trying to rewrite the expression
$$
 A'A - A'B(B'B+C'C)^{-1}B'A ?
$$

Comment: Or rather, would you say that we just want to compute the matrix $A'A - A'B(B'B+C'C)^{-1}B'A$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, I want to compute this equation

Comment: Depending on the shape of your matrices, you might find the [Woodbury Matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) useful.  In particular, we have
$$
(C'C + B'B)^{-1} = C'C - [C'C]^{-1}B'(I + B[C'C]^{-1}B')^{-1}B[C'C]^{-1}
$$
I'm not sure if $(I + B[C'C]^{-1}B')$ is easy to find an inverse of in this context.  If $B$ is low-rank, we could also compute the inverse of $(I + B[C'C]^{-1}B')$ with a series of rank-1 updates.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you for your effort , I have listed the detail below

Comment: @Mr.Guo I'm glad that you found my suggestion to be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute $X:=(B^TB+C^TC)^{-1}B^TA$, you never actually compute $(B^TB+C^TC)^{-1}$, but instead you solve $(B^TB+C^TC)X=B^TA$. Since $C$ is upper triangular, you can see $C^T$ as the Cholesky factor of $C^TC$. You can [update the Cholesky factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Rank-one_update) $C^T$ to account for the low rank update $B^TB$ (via repeated rank-1 updates). That will give you a new Cholesky factor $L$ such that $LL^T = B^TB+C^TC$. Then all you need to do is solve $LL^TX = B^TA$, which is relatively easy.

Comment: cholesky factor update is a good idea, I'm using eigen , but I didn't find the rank one update for C, it only have interface for C'C which need mutiply first, so I think @Omnomnomnom 's idea is more fitting for me :) , I have listed the detail below

Comment: @Mr.Guo what do you mean by "I didn't find the rank one update for C, it only have interface for C'C which need mutiply first"?

Comment: I mean Eigen have no good interface for up-triangulate matrix  rank-one update :)

Comment: @Mr.Guo I think $C$ is of the LLT type with the UpLo flag set to upper, and that you can use [this procedure](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LLT.html#aae1ee59cb3c46723721da6fd72acc21a).

Answer (score 1):

hi @Omnomnomnom you have given me a better hint to solve this problem , I'd like to list it here
I have checked your equation it's correct except one little mistaken, it should be:

$ (C'C+B'B)^{-1} = (C'C)^{-1} - (C'C)^{-1}B'(I+B(C'C)^{-1}B')^{-1}B(C'C)^{-1} $

I think it's a good solution because B is (small rows * big cols) matrix, we can get

$D = (C'C)^{-1}$

$E = BDB'$

$F = (I+E)^{-1}$

D,E,F are all easy computed, so the result is :

$ (C'C+B'B)^{-1} = D - DB'FBD $

and finally,

$ result = A'A-A'B(B'B+C'C)^{-1}B'A = A'(I-B(B'B+C'C)^{-1}B')A = A'(I-BDB' + BDB'FBDB')A = A'(I-E+EFE)A$